# Create unique list of objects by any property

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, set

i'm trying to create Generic class that will have behavior of `List` but accept `Field` of `String` as a name of the property that should determine the uniqueness.
For example we have class `User`:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to have class lets say name `UniqueList`.
And to be able to provide to constructor `User.class.getDeclaredField("name")`, this will make this list of users to be unique by the property name of the User, and this list will not be able to contain two User object with name "John" for example.

As for now i tried to create class that extends `ArrayList<T>` and implements `Set<T>` but i start to have a mess in the logic.
Maybe some one already have something like this and can share or help to understand how to implement it.
Currently code that i have:

```
public class UniqueValueList<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Set<T> {

    private String uniqueValueKey;
    private Field keyField;
    HashMap<Object, T> hashMap;

    public UniqueValueList(Class c, String keyName) {
        hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            keyField = c.getDeclaredField(keyName);
            keyField.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        try {
            //get value of the key from provided object.
            Object keyValue = keyField.get(t);
            if (hashMap.containsKey(keyValue)) {
                hashMap.remove(keyValue);
            }
            hashMap.put(keyValue, t);
            super.add(t);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return super.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return super.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return super.contains(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think instead of extending ArrayList and implementing Set both, you should only extend ArrayList and override its add method.Check if list contains by list.contains(data) and if not then only add it in list, which will help in uniqueness.

Comment: This is the regular way and i would have to do nested for loop for that, i'm trying to avoid it. That is why i implement set

Comment: Then you can instead use LinkedHashset. So that order and uniqueness both is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be right. Don't forget to remove object from the list when replacing:

```
    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        try {
            //get value of the key from provided object.
            Object keyValue = keyField.get(t);
            if (hashMap.containsKey(keyValue)) {
                super.remove(hashMap.get(keyValue)); // << remove old object from list
                hashMap.remove(keyValue);
            }
            hashMap.put(keyValue, t);
            super.add(t);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Override other add/remove methods accordingly. Keep in mind that ArrayList extends List, so you need to override ArrayList's add/remove methods as well (e.g. `add(int index, E element)`, `remove(int index)` etc.)